# Convert column using date and append to csv file

Tags: text-processing, awk, osx, date, csv

I have a CSV where the first column has a string that represents datetime. I would like to add an extra column with that datetime converted to epoch.
I tried the following:

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN{ OFS="," } {$14=$(date -jf "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p" $1 "+%s"); print}’ mycsv.csv > test
```

I get:

```
awk: illegal field $(0%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p﻿"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM"+%s), name "(null)"
 input record number 1, file mycsv.csv
 source line number 1
```

I know that the date conversion for the field works so I am doing something wrong with the syntax.
How can I do what I want?

Comment: I retagged your question to include awk and text processing. You had both Linux and OSX in there; I arbitrarily removed OS X -- edit it back in if I am wrong, please.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I think it ought to be tagged `osx` as he's using macOS specific `date`. I'm swapping the linux tag out, or he'll get GNU date answers.

Comment: Good catch on the date command, Kusalananda - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have GNU `date` and hence the command line options are different for me. But you problem seems to be awk's syntax: You can not use the shell subprocess construct `$(...)` inside awk scripts. You need to you the `system()` function, which gets passed a string. Therefore you need to construct a valid shell command into an awk string that you can pass to system inside the awk script.

Something like this:

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN{ OFS="," } {$14=system("date -jf \"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p\" \""$1"\" \"+%s\""); print}' mycsv.csv > test
```

or for better readablility

```
awk -F "," '
  BEGIN{ OFS="," }
  {
    $14 = system("date -jf \"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p\" \"" $1 "\" \"+%s\"");
    print
  }' \
  mycsv.csv > test
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the quotes. Now I get: `Failed conversion of ``11/24/2016'' using format ``%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p''
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`

Comment: Sorry I can not reproduce this or see the problem right now. Try to paste the awk script into a seperate file (call it `foo.awk`) and see if an editor with syntax highlighting can help you spot the problem.

Comment: Which editor in OSX would that be? In vim nothing is indicated

Comment: What is the `system`? If I do `man system` I get: SYSTEM(3)                BSD Library Functions Manual                SYSTEM(3)

NAME
     system -- pass a command to the shell

Comment: This works: `awk -F "," 'BEGIN{ OFS="," } {$14=system("date -jf \"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p\" \"1/27/2017 10:48:20 AM\" \"+%s\""); print}'` but if I replace with $1 it does not. I think the problem is that the $1 already has double quotes. How can I strip them?

Comment: This works now: `awk -F "," 'BEGIN{ OFS="," } {gsub(/"/, "", $1);$14=system("date -jf \"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p\" \""$1"\" \"+%s\""); print}' mycsv.csv > test` but I get one error only `Failed conversion of ``1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM'' using format ``%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p''
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`

Comment: Seems that your answer gave the correct direction. I'll open another question about the parsing issue. I get this error only for the first line and I don't understand why

Comment: Maybe %m expects two digits.  An editor on OSX could be Xcode or vim.

Comment: @Jim the `system()` we are talking about is a function in the awk language. You can read about it in `man awk`. I think it is the awk wrapper around the system(3) you mention.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU `awk` (which should be available on OSX via `brew` I think) then you could use the internal `mktime` and `strftime` instead of relying on system `date`.

Unfortunately your input format isn't in the *datespec* format expected by `mktime`, so some splitting and rearranging of the time string is required. For example, given

```
$ cat file.csv 
09/23/2016 11:12:19 AM,field2,field3
```

then

```
gawk -F, '
  {
    split($1,a,/[/: ]/);
    ts = sprintf("%4d %02d %02d %2d %2d %2d", a[3], a[2], a[1], a[7] ~ /^[Pp]/ ? a[4]+12 : a[4], a[5], a[6]); 
    $0 = strftime("%s", mktime(ts)) FS $0
  } 1' file.csv
1510243939,09/23/2016 11:12:19 AM,field2,field3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (`mlr`, available on macOS via Homebrew as the `miller` package), and assuming that your input is a header-less CSV file and that you want to write the Unix timestamp into field 14 by parsing the formatted date in field 1:

```bash
mlr --csv -N put '$14 = strptime($1,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")' mycsv.csv
```

If you have headers, then drop the `-N` option and use named fields instead of numeric fields, e.g. `$timestamp = strptime($date, ...)`.

The `strptime()` function parses a formatted date using the provided pattern and returns a Unix timestamp.

For the date mentioned  in the question, assuming it's in the UTC timezone, the new field would get the value `1485774895.000000`. Would you want to take the local timezone into account, use `strptime_local()` in place of `strptime()`. Would you want only the integer part of the Unix timestamp, wrap the call to `strptime()` in `int(...)`.